# OpenFileDialog. How about "Specify Directory Dialog"?

Tags: c#, directory, openfiledialog

On a file path field, I want to capture the directory path like:

```
textbox1.Text = directory path
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I am using VS 2008 SP1. This all I need:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog profilePath = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    if (profilePath.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)        
    {
        profilePathTextBox.Text = profilePath.SelectedPath;
    }
    else
    {
        profilePathTextBox.Text = "Please Specify The Profile Path";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a FolderBrowserDialog class that you can use if you want the user to select a folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result.Equals(get_DialogResult().OK)) {
    textbox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.get_SelectedPath();
}
```

If all you want is to get the direcotory from a full path, you can do this:

```
textbox1.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\windows\temp\myfile.txt");
```

This will set the Text-property to "c:\windows\temp\"

Comment: Oh man, I thought this was a good solution until I realized which dialog this shows - I HATE that dialog! [http://i.imgur.com/2uGPK.png](http://i.imgur.com/2uGPK.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a terrible, non-user friendly dialog*, try [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) or see other answers to [How do you configure an OpenFileDialog to select folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders). The only downside I see to Ookii is that it requires .NET 4 Full, not just Client Profile. But the source is included in the download, so I'm going to work on that. Too bad the license isn't LGPL or similar...

See also: [WinForms message box with textual buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342895/winforms-message-box-with-textual-buttons)

*This is what FolderBrowserDialog looks like:

[image: Ugly, unfriendly folder browser dialog]