# WinForms message box with textual buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

Windows 7(?) introduced a new message box feature (I'm not sure what it is called so I've uploaded a picture). How can I create such a box in C# with WinForms?

[image: Windows new message box]

Comment: TaskDialog is available in the Windows API Code Pack: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out, the TaskDialog .NET API is provided by the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). There is an [interesting article (German)](http://www.hinzberg.net/api7/api7/downlaods_files/windows7api.pdf) about task dialogs and other functionality provided by the API.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code project article: [Task Dialog WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/TaskDialogWinForms.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760441.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is a library with all vista and win7 dialogs:

http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/

The downside is that it requires full .Net not just client profile.