# using OpenFileDialog for directory, not FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I want to have a Folder browser in my application, but **I don't** want to use the FolderBrowserDialog.  (For several reasons, such as it's painful to use)

I want to use the standard OpenFileDialog, but modified for the directories.

As an example, [µTorrent](http://utorrent.com/) has a nice implementation of it (Preferences/Directories/Put new downloads in:).  The standard Open File Dialog enable the user to:

- paste full paths in the text field at bottom
- use "Favorite Links" bar on Vista
- use Search on Vista
- auto remember last directory
- more...

Does anybody know how to implement this?  In C#.

Comment: Seems a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders

Comment: Duplicate of this question: - [How do you configure an OpenFileDIalog to select folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about uTorrent but this sounds pretty much like new Vista's [IFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with FOS_PICKFOLDERS option set. Generic C# code for it would go something like:

```
var frm = (IFileDialog)(new FileOpenDialogRCW());
uint options;
frm.GetOptions(out options);
options |= FOS_PICKFOLDERS;
frm.SetOptions(options);

if (frm.Show(owner.Handle) == S_OK) {
    IShellItem shellItem;
    frm.GetResult(out shellItem);
    IntPtr pszString;
    shellItem.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, out pszString);
    this.Folder = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pszString);
}
```

Full code can be found [here](http://www.jmedved.com/2011/12/openfolderdialog/).

Answer (score 1):

[WindowsAPICodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack/1.1.0)

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog();
dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15456640/117870) by [leetNightShade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353094/leetnightshade) for a working solution.

There are three things I believe make this solution much better than all the others.

1. **It is simple to use.** 
   It only requires you include two files (which can be combined to one anyway) in your project.
2. It falls back to the standard [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) when used on XP or older systems.
3. The author grants permission to use the code for any purpose you deem fit.

   > There’s no license as such as you are free to take and do with the code what you will.

Download the code [here](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136).