# Forms.OpenFileDialog() and Forms.FolderBrowserDialog() initial path behavior

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

In my application I use both `OpenFileDialog` and `FolderBrowserDialog` on button click handlers:

```
var fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

var folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
```

Strange thing is that when calling `OpenFileDialog` it starts in explorer from folder in which file was chosen last time.
But `FolderBrowserDialog` opens MyComputer each time in explorer no matter what folder was chosen last time. How can I get same behavior (remembering last chosen folder) for `FolderBrowserDialog'?

It's also interesting where 'OpenFileDialog' stores folder of last chosen file? Does windows stores it for each application?

Comment: Note that the settings for the InitialDirectory in the OpenFileDialog is wrong. This should be an actual path not an enum converted to a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `FolderBrowserDialog`'s selected folder using the `SelectedPath` property before opening:

```
var folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDialog.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
folderDialog.SelectedPath = <variable_where_you_stored_the_last_path>;
```

For example:

```
private string _lastFolderDialog = null;
// ...
var folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDialog.SelectedPath = _lastFolderDialog;
if(folderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  _lastFolderDialog = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
}
```

As for the `OpenFileDialog`, I think you mean:

```
fileDialog.InitialDirectory =
               Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
```

However that won't work, since `MyComputer` doesn't have a path. Try this instead:

```
fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
```

You can check for other CLSIDs in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID`

As you have already discovered, if `InitialDirectory` is set to `null`, it'll remember the last opened folder. This won't happen with `FolderBrowserDialog` though

---

All that said, and as I stated in the comments, the `FolderBrowserDialog` is pretty much obsolete and you should not use it at all. According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx) for the native API (`SHBrowseForFolder`) that supports it:

> For Windows Vista or later, it is recommended that you use IFileDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option rather than the SHBrowseForFolder function. This uses the Open Files dialog in pick folders mode and is the preferred implementation.

You may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600346/using-openfiledialog-for-directory-not-folderbrowserdialog) (which in turn links to [this page](https://www.medo64.com/2011/12/openfolderdialog)) or [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755119/selectfolderdialog-in-net) on how to implement `IFileDialog` with `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` in .NET

Comment: regarding fileDialog - I deleted second line and it workd as I want (remembering last directory) by default. How can I get folderDialog work same way?

Comment: @Dork store the result of `folderDialog.SelectedPath` somewhere after calling `ShowDialog()`, and then set it before calling `ShowDialog` again. I don't think the `FolderBrowserDialog` does that by itself

Comment: thx.. I thought they have same nature and should work similarly

Comment: @Dork nope, not actually... `OpenFileDialog` is in the Win32 API much prior to `SHBrowseForFolder` (which is what `FolderBrowserDialog` is made with). I'm not sure if there's a native implementation of `FOS_PICKFOLDERS`, but that's what you should be using: `FolderBrowserDialog` is obsolete and Microsoft doesn't recommend using it (since Vista on), despite many applications still using it (as a bad dialog as it is)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600346/using-openfiledialog-for-directory-not-folderbrowserdialog) (and the accepted answer): this is the preferred method to browse for folders in Vista or later