# Visual Studio 2008 folder browser dialog

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

In Visual Studio 2008 there is a folder browser dialog that looks like this (very similar to file open dialog):

[image: Dialog]

Does anyone know how to invoke it from code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end I just used the [VistaBridge](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge) library to open it.

Comment: I have searched such dialog in VistaBridge and found nothing, what is the class name of FolderBrawser analog in VistaBridge?

Answer (score 21):

If you're using C#, this solution is for you. Source code provided here: http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136 (.NET Win 7-style folder select dialog). [Update: if site is dead, here's a [wayback machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230408013724/http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136).]

> How does it work?
> It turns out that the ability to show a Vista-like dialog is present in .NET but the methods are not public. So the ShowDialog() method uses reflection to call CreateVistaDialog and pass in all the parameters. The technique to do this is taken from the Google code project FED.

You don't need to use a whole library like VistaBridge, or a Windows API code pack, to get a nice Folder Dialogue, just two small source files.  Gives you a nice folder dialogue like this:

[image]

Comment: This solution works without using VistaBridge and it provides a fallback for XP and older.

Comment: This is a great solution. It simply works and unlike Windows API code pack this has no license restrictions. Thank you!

Comment: It should be mentioned that the Reflector class is from [Front-End for Dosbox](http://code.google.com/p/fed/) and this is GPL v2. So it *has* license restrictions.

Comment: July 2023: the linked site, lyquidity.com, appears to be gone.

Comment: @fadden Wayback machine and download still works: https://web.archive.org/web/20230408013724/http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136

Answer (score 1):

Is this the pinvoke of [SHBrowseForFolder](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHBrowseForFolder.html), with the BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE style? If so there is an example on that page.

Answer (score -2):

Drag a FolderBrowserDialog component from the Dialogs tab of the Toolbox to the form.
Add this code to you button handler.

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.label1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
```

Comment: Please look at the attached image. I want THAT folder browser dialog and not the regular ugly one.