# How can I make this control (may a kind of FolderBrowser)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

As you can see in the picture below, this looks like a file dialog and folder browser. This dialog can select only folder(not file). Is this a custom control? If so, then please give me advice on how to make it. This is a Winforms application.

[image]

Comment: can you please tell us if you are trying to do this with WPF or with Windows Forms? and did you mean "... but **not** files" instead of "but file"?

Comment: ok thankyou, this is winform application which can select only folder not file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the native Vista IFileDialog based version of OpenFileDialog.  With the FOS_PICKFOLDERS turned on.  That option is not exposed in .NET, it isn't available on earlier versions of Windows.  You can get a wrapper for it from the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), CommonOpenFileDialog.IsFolderPicker property.

Comment: Do earlier versions of Windows fall back to the old tree view folder browser?

Comment: @Bolt - there's no fallback in the code pack wrapper, it will simply fail trying to create the IFileDialog instance.  It has to be done by your own code, Environment.OSVersion property.

Comment: THANKYOU IT LOOKS SIMILLAR (not tested yet)

Answer (score 0):

use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx):

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.Description = "Select a folder";
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
String selectedFolder = String.Empty;
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    selectedFolder = dialog.SelectedPath;
}
dialog.Dispose();
```

The FolderBrowserDialog has a different user interface than the Dialog you showed in your screenshot. If it needs to look like that, how about reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/514368/1106367)?

You should also consider using the third-party [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) wrapper classes.