# How to use Open File Dialog to Select a Folder

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you configure an OpenFileDIalog to select folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)

I'm using C# and I want to completely avoid SelectFolderDialog to select a folder. Instead, I want to use something closer to a OpenFileDialog just to select a folder.

For a more visual example, I'm looking for something close (if not exactly) like the following: http://i44.tinypic.com/x38tx1.png

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The Vista IFileDialog interface exposes this option.  Available in the Windows API Code Pack, CommonOpenFileDialog class, IsFolderPicker property.

Comment: @HansPassant: If you add that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Could you give an example of this? I agree with Heinzi.

Comment: @Demasterpl: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15456640/117870 which links to [this article](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136 ".NET Win 7-style folder select dialog") for a working solution

Comment: thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh you asked exactly what i was looking for! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The folder selection dialog of Windows Vista looks quite similar to what you want. Unfortunately, .NET's `FolderBrowserDialog` shows the old Windows-XP-like dialog, which you want to avoid.

To access this Vista-style dialog, you can either

- use some third-party .NET library (e.g. [Ookii.Dialogs](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf)),
- use the relevant Windows API calls or
- use the [Windows API Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665/87698):

  ```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

    ...

    var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog(); 
    dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
    CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
  ```

  Note that this dialog is not available on operating systems older than Windows Vista, so be sure to check `CommonFileDialog.IsPlatformSupported` first.

Comment: Both Winforms in 3.5 and WPF in 4.0 were updated to use the Vista dialog.

Comment: @HansPassant: No. I just tried it: `new FolderBrowserDialog().ShowDialog();` in a .NET 4.0 WinForms app shows the same old, ugly FolderBrowserDialog.

Comment: Check the FileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled property.

Comment: @HansPassant: `FolderBrowserDialog` does not derive from `FileDialog`. Hence, it lacks this property (and its functionality).

Comment: Ah, we're talking about different classes.  Never mind.

Comment: Are there any "solid" (Simple) examples on use of the Windows API calls?

Comment: I wish I could post an example, but the question has been closed. In my opinion, this is a totally different question than the possible duplicate listed above.

Comment: Can this be used to select multiple files AND folders at the same time? I would like to be able to either select one or multiple files, one or multiple folders, or both at the same time. What are the correct parameters?

Comment: var dialog = New CommonOpenFileDialog();  <-- VS2013 errors out with 'New'.  Change it to 'new' for it to work.

Comment: @CaTx: Thanks. That happens when you get too much exposure to VB...

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss, this is exactly what i was looking for! and simplest one. like Visual Studio folder browsing(for selecting project path)

Comment: this one changes the font size in higher resolution displays like 4K.