# Get multiple checked files and folders from one dialog simultenously

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need some Dialog that allows me select multiple items (files nad folders) simultenously and retrieve their paths for folders and paths + file names for files.

OpenFileDIalog allows me to multiselect files. FolderBrowseDialog allows me to multiselect directories. How can I combine functionality of this two windows? The best solution seems to be display sth. like OpenFileDialog with multiselection and ability to get checked folder path.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you imagine a use case scenario to select multiple files sperad over different directories? or do you want to select multiple files AND directories within the same directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select both files and folders using OpenFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841768/select-both-files-and-folders-using-openfiledialog)

Comment: Mong Zhu - inside some directory called e.g "Test" I have 5 files called test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt, test4.txt, test5.txt and 3 folders called: fol1, fol2 and fol3. I need select test3.txt, test4,.txt files and fol2 and fol3 folders and retrieve their names after Ok click button.

Comment: did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442731/5174469) work for you? should be easy to try

Comment: All those solutions describes how to create one window used in 2 ways, as file dialog or folders dialog. None of them works simultenously for files and folders.

Comment: Most of the build-in File and Folder selectors only show contents of one folder at a time. And when you switch folders any selected items from the previous folder are lost. I think you are out of luck and the only solution would be to write your own.

Comment: Jeff R. - I don't want to change folder during selection. I need the possibility to choose e.g. 2 folders and 3 files from current folder.