# How do a make this type of select folder dialog in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

So I recently tried to the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but much to my disappointment it was not like the following screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/s2LHqxA.png]

But instead it was formatted and as I think, hard to navigate with like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/rfSnt8C.png]

How would I go about getting the other version where it's a dialog box asking for what folder to save to like the select file type natively, instead of what I think is this hard to navigate menu.

Comment: are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: AFAIK `FolderBrowserDialog` used to be like second screen shot only. If you want something different you have to roll your own.

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue what I'm using. I'm very new to this and this is probably the 3rd or 4th time I've programmed in C#.... infact this is the first time I've had to work with invoke.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't quite know how to change it to that, any suggestions?

Comment: Please show some code, since you shouldn't be working with invoke to get the OpenXXDialog inside C#

Comment: Oh no, I meant I had to use invoke for the first to call a function I defined on another thread for logging output to a text box.

Comment: @BerndLinde the OP isn't working with Invoke, the desired folder is actually the Vista-style File Dialog which isn't available in .NET. In fact, using native calls *is* one of the solutions to this.

Comment: There are many similar questions, eg [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227917/how-to-use-open-file-dialog-to-select-a-folder). The easiest option, using the Windows API Code pack is  tricky because MS pulled the code a while ago. Many people uploaded the code to GitHub though and you can find unofficial NuGet packages, eg [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I just installed it after browsing related questions how ever I'm clueless how to use it... **Edit** I think I found out thanks to your link. **Edit2:** Odd if I add it to my use list it's not a valid class still.

Comment: I'm still looking for a native way instead of this, it works but it's still not quite desired.. anything else? I could accept the WindowsAPICodePack I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *CommonOpenFileDialog*  class from the NuGet Package *"Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell"* will answer your request.

Set IsFolderPicker property to *true*  and that's it.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;     

private bool SelectFolder(out string fileName)
{
    CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
        fileName = dialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `like the select file type natively` from the original question but thanks for an answer anyways that's surely to help others. This requires a NuGet package and including a things to the project rather than a native method.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are using `FolderBrowserDialog` instead of `OpenFileDialog`

you can check the below

```
 private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Title = "Browse File";
            fileDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            fileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            fileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFileName.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to select a file, and by the rest of the copy pasted code it seems to be reused from a `.txt` file but changed for All files `*.*`

Comment: you can substring the folder name from it. the interface you need isn't provided for folder selection Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227917/how-to-use-open-file-dialog-to-select-a-folder.

Comment: `txtFileName` shows this is probably from code to select a `txt` filetype. I'm still doing research and I may find another way natively in windows to resolve this as I don't want an external package to add in.

Comment: actually txtFileName is a Text box Controll I just prefix them with txt :). anw if you find a way to accomplish what you need  please post it here as an answer.