# How can I use the folder browser that is used by VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, folderbrowserdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you configure an OpenFileDialog to select folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)

My app uses the FolderBrowserDialog in Windows.Forms. I would prefer to use the folder browser used by VS2012 when you are deciding where to put a new project. Can someone point me to the correct class?

To be more specific, when you create a new project in VS2012 or VS2010, you get a new project dialog box. In that box you can click a browse button to set the location of project. A very nice dialog box is opened to let you select your folder. Here is a image on a Win 7 system.

[image: Folder browser]

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are looking for?  Your post is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to make a default path for Open Dialog?

In the openFileDialog1 Properties  find a field called initial directory and put C:\\Program Files\\MyFolder.

Next time you will use Open Dialog it will start with MyFolder folder from your C disk.

Comment: I was asking which class to use. I see it must be OpenFileDialog with special settings. Thanks.

Comment: You can find it in ToolBox->Dialogs-> and there you can choose which one is better feet for you.