# Usage of GetOpenFileName() API in VC++ for opening a folder & NOT a file

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dialog, menuitem

BOOL WINAPI GetOpenFileName(
      *Inout*  LPOPENFILENAME lpofn
    );

is used for opening a file in a VC++ program, say

> C:\Hello\World\abc.txt

.
But I want to use this function to select a folder

> C:\Hello\World
>   instaed of a file in it.

I guess I need to make some changes to the members of the structure "OPENFILENAME". Can anyone kindly lemme know how do I achieve this in a VC++ program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders which is not C++ but will give you the idea.

Answer (score 4):

`GetOpenFileName` does not support folder selection at all.

Your options are:

- `SHBrowseForFolder` which is available on Windows 2000 and later, but looks a bit ugly.
- `IFileDialog` which is the platform native folder chooser, but only available on Vista or later. To make the dialog behave as a folder picker, pass `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` to `SetOptions`.

In my opinion the best result for the user is to use `IFileDialog` where available, but fall back to `SHBrowseForFolder` for older operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

There's [ShBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115.aspx).  Plenty of C++ examples around if you search.