# Select a Folder with dialog box (no SHBrowseForFolder) C++

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to know how to display a dialog box with the option for select a folder. No using SHBrowseForFolder.

I search and people say that is not possible with GetOpenFileName. Witch api? how to get?

But I show a picture where it is possible:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use ShBrowseForFolder? It's the standard way of doing this.

Comment: You can try this: http://www.abstraction.net/content/articles/how%20to%20customize%20the%20standard%20win32%20browse%20for%20folder%20dialog.htm

Comment: Or this (starting with Vista): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is IFileOpenDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option turned on.

Comment: `IFileOpenDialog`, as @HansPassant says. It's documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com), and a search here or via Google should turn up C++ examples of using it.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596493/usage-of-getopenfilename-api-in-vc-for-opening-a-folder-not-a-file