# Is there a way to get the directory pathway using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, trim, openfiledialog

I am using a button to get details about a directory that is selected by the user using something like OpenFileDialog in C#.  At the moment I can only select a file and get the full pathway of that file.  Is there a way that I can just get pathway without having to select a file or even trim the file name off the end of the pathway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you configure an OpenFileDialog to select folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `FolderBrowserDialog`.

You should also look at the functions in the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path).