# VBNET browse for folder dialog type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When adding a FolderBrowserDialog class in VBNET, this is the type of browse window you get:

[image]

How can I get THIS type of browse window (so it's easier to just paste in a path instead of having to twirl lots of arrows)?

[image]

Comment: The second one only works for **files**. It has no way to select a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use OpenFileDialog instead of folderbrowerDialog. Read more about it 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Read this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders) for opening directories using openFileDialog

Comment: Yes, this is correct but in order to use it for selecting a folder, you will need to use OpenFileDialog in your own modified class which I see lots of documentation on that I can figure it out so I will mark your answer as answered since it pointed me in the correct direction.