# Better FolderDialog for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I'm hesitant to ask this question because I'm sure it must already be answered somewhere, but I've been searching for hours and either I'm drowning in all the noise or I simply can't find an elegant solution for VB.NET.

Essentially, my problem is identical to this question, but applied to VB.NET:

[How do you configure an OpenFileDialog to select folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)

http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136

Can someone please help direct me to the cleanest/most elegant solution?

I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, the `FolderBrowserDialog` is awful. I use the standard `SaveFileDialog`, and ignore the filename.

```
Dim strFolder As String = ""
Using dlg As New SaveFileDialog With {.AddExtension = True,
                                      .AutoUpgradeEnabled = True,
                                      .CreatePrompt = False,
                                      .OverwritePrompt = False,
                                      .CheckFileExists = False,
                                      .CheckPathExists = True,
                                      .FileName = "Folder selection",
                                      .Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*",
                                      .FilterIndex = 1,
                                      .InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
                                      .SupportMultiDottedExtensions = True,
                                      .Title = "Select folder",
                                      .ValidateNames = True}
  If dlg.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim strFilename As String = dlg.FileName
    strFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFilename)
  End If
End Using
MsgBox(strFolder)
```