# Open Directory with Special Panel in C# wpf

Tags: wpf

I Open a Folder in C# with following codes. But I want to disable the address bar so that someone does not understand the file's address. And nobody can go to the previous or next folder!

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"D:\Project WPF\Atlas\Samle\D-File\MyFiles");
```

Or open the Explorer in the C# Window.
[image]

Comment: This might answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using ExplorerBrowser. This will help embed the explorer window in your application and will give you more control over what you wish to show.